# Ask for user name in http headers. IE

Tags: internet-explorer, http, active-directory

Is there a way to ask the `browser(IE)` to pass the user name that accessing the webpage in the `HTTP` Headers? I want to restrict access to the page without having a log in page. Is this possible since we're on corporate network with AC?

Comment: You're looking for NTLM auth.

Comment: Good. I now need to find an example about how to use it on IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by enabling (Integrated or Basic) Authentication for your web application in IIS.

When IIS received a request for a resource (file/directory/handler/etc) that requires Authentication, it sends back a relevant response with HTTP Status Code 401. When the browser receives this response, it typically sends the currently logged on user in a header called `Authentication` or it first pops up a dialog asking the user for credentials (and then still sends the `Authentication` header with the request).

Comment: I enabled Windows Authentication